# Why does ArcPy plot just one point when there are many?

Tags: arcpy, point, arcgis-pro, python-window

Why does following ArcPy code, when run in Python window in ArcGIS Pro, plot only one point, the last one in for loop, that is (538973.76, 6478442.80)?

My aim was to get all the points (x,y) plotted.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.outputCoordinateSystem = r"C:\temp\coordsys.prj"
env.workspace = r"C:\test.gdb"

x = [538993.76, 538983.76, 538973.76]
y = [6478462.80, 6478452.80, 6478442.80]

for i in range(len(x)):
   point = arcpy.Point(x[i],y[i])
   pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
   arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometry, "Hydrant")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hornbydd says, you're overwriting the output once for every point.  If you want a single output with all of the points, then feed a list of geometries into CopyFeatures:

```
x = [538993.76, 538983.76, 538973.76]
y = [6478462.80, 6478452.80, 6478442.80]

geometries = []

for px, py in zip(x, y):
   point = arcpy.Point(px, py)
   pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
   geometries.append(pointGeometry)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(geometries, "Hydrant")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy features tool is copying the point to a featureclass you are calling Hydrant. If the dataset exists then it gets overwritten.

A solution is to make the file name change on each loop so you create as many datasets as points you are creating, then as a final step in your code merge them all into one dataset.

Alternatively you can directly append data into an existing featureclass using insert cursors, this would avoid the creation of the intermediate datasets.